# How come the app does not load with this java code?

Tags: java, android, calculator

I am trying to build a calculator and the problem seems to lie with this java code. I tried it with the standard java code by the Android SDK and the layout works. But when I load the code below, it does not. I do not understand why it would not load. I am new to java and this is killing me. Please help. (I put the logcat on the bottom.)

```
package com.haildark.calculator;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Calc extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

   Button one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, zero, add, sub, mul, div, cancel, equal;
   EditText disp;
   int op1;
   int op2;
   String optr;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.calc);

       one = (Button) findViewById(R.id.onebtn);
       two = (Button) findViewById(R.id.twobtn);
       three = (Button) findViewById(R.id.threebtn);
       four = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fourbtn);
       five = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fivebtn);
       six = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sixbtn);
       seven = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sevenbtn);
       eight = (Button) findViewById(R.id.eightbtn);
       nine = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ninebtn);
       zero = (Button) findViewById(R.id.zerobtn);
       add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addbtn);
       sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.minusbtn);
       mul = (Button) findViewById(R.id.multiplicationbtn);
       div = (Button) findViewById(R.id.divisionbtn);
       cancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cbtn);
       equal = (Button) findViewById(R.id.equalbtn);

       disp = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

       try{
           one.setOnClickListener(this);

           two.setOnClickListener(this);

           three.setOnClickListener(this);

           four.setOnClickListener(this);

           five.setOnClickListener(this);

           six.setOnClickListener(this);

           seven.setOnClickListener(this);

           eight.setOnClickListener(this);

           nine.setOnClickListener(this);

           zero.setOnClickListener(this);

           cancel.setOnClickListener(this);

           add.setOnClickListener(this);

           sub.setOnClickListener(this);

           mul.setOnClickListener(this);

           div.setOnClickListener(this);

           equal.setOnClickListener(this);
       }
       catch(Exception e){

       }
   }
   public void operation(){
       if(optr.equals("+")){
           op2 = Integer.parseInt(disp.getText().toString());
           disp.setText("");
           op1 = op1 + op2;
           disp.setText("Result : " + Integer.toString(op1));
       }
       else if(optr.equals("-")){
           op2 = Integer.parseInt(disp.getText().toString());
           disp.setText("");
           op1 = op1 - op2;
           disp.setText("Result : " + Integer.toString(op1));
       }
       else if(optr.equals("*")){
           op2 = Integer.parseInt(disp.getText().toString());
           disp.setText("");
           op1 = op1 * op2;
           disp.setText("Result : " + Integer.toString(op1));
       }
       else if(optr.equals("/")){
           op2 = Integer.parseInt(disp.getText().toString());
           disp.setText("");
           op1 = op1 / op2;
           disp.setText("Result : " + Integer.toString(op1));
       }
   }
   @Override
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
       Editable str =  disp.getText();
       switch(arg0.getId()){
           case R.id.onebtn:
               if(op2 != 0){
                   op2 = 0;
                   disp.setText("");
               }
               str = str.append(two.getText());
               disp.setText(str);
           break;
           case R.id.twobtn:
               if(op2 != 0){
                   op2 = 0;
                   disp.setText("");
               }
               str = str.append(two.getText());
               disp.setText(str);
           break;
           case R.id.threebtn:
               if(op2 != 0){
                   op2 = 0;
                   disp.setText("");
               }
               str = str.append(three.getText());
               disp.setText(str);
           break;
           case R.id.fourbtn:
               if(op2 != 0){
                   op2 = 0;
                   disp.setText("");
               }
               str = str.append(four.getText());
               disp.setText(str);
           break;
           case R.id.fivebtn:
               if(op2 != 0){
                   op2 = 0;
                   disp.setText("");
               }
               str = str.append(five.getText());
               disp.setText(str);
           break;
           case R.id.sixbtn:
               if(op2 != 0){
                   op2 = 0;
                   disp.setText("");
               }
               str = str.append(six.getText());
               disp.setText(str);
           break;
           case R.id.sevenbtn:
               if(op2 != 0){
                   op2 = 0;
                   disp.setText("");
               }
               str = str.append(eight.getText());
               disp.setText(str);
           break;
           case R.id.eightbtn:
               if(op2 != 0){
                   op2 = 0;
                   disp.setText("");
               }
               str = str.append(nine.getText());
               disp.setText(str);

           break;
           case R.id.ninebtn:
               if(op2 != 0){
                   op2 = 0;
                   disp.setText("");
               }
               str = str.append(zero.getText());
               disp.setText(str);

           break;
           case R.id.cbtn:
               op1 = 0;
               op2 = 0;
               disp.setText("");
               disp.setHint("Perform Operation :)");

           break;
           case R.id.addbtn:
               optr = "+";
               if(op1 == 0){
                   op1 = Integer.parseInt(disp.getText().toString());
                   disp.setText("");
               }
               else if(op2 != 0){
                   op2 = 0;
                   disp.setText("");
               }
               else{
                   op2 = Integer.parseInt(disp.getText().toString());
                   disp.setText("");
                   op1 = op1 + op2;
                   disp.setText("Result : " + Integer.toString(op1));
               }
           break;
           case R.id.minusbtn:
               optr = "-";
               if(op1 == 0){
                   op1 = Integer.parseInt(disp.getText().toString());
                   disp.setText("");
               }
               else if(op2 != 0){
                   op2 = 0;
                   disp.setText("");
               }
               else{
                   op2 = Integer.parseInt(disp.getText().toString());
                   disp.setText("");
                   op1 = op1 - op2;
                   disp.setText("Result : " + Integer.toString(op1));
               }
           break;
           case R.id.multiplicationbtn:
               optr = "*";
               if(op1 == 0){
                   op1 = Integer.parseInt(disp.getText().toString());
                   disp.setText("");
               }
               else if(op2 != 0){
                   op2 = 0;
                   disp.setText("");
               }
               else{
                   op2 = Integer.parseInt(disp.getText().toString());
                   disp.setText("");
                   op1 = op1 * op2;
                   disp.setText("Result : " + Integer.toString(op1));
               }
           break;
           case R.id.divisionbtn:
               optr = "/";
               if(op1 == 0){
                   op1 = Integer.parseInt(disp.getText().toString());
                   disp.setText("");
               }
               else if(op2 != 0){
                   op2 = 0;
                   disp.setText("");
               }
               else{
                   op2 = Integer.parseInt(disp.getText().toString());
                   disp.setText("");
                   op1 = op1 / op2;
                   disp.setText("Result : " + Integer.toString(op1));
               }
           break;
           case R.id.equalbtn:
               if(!optr.equals(null)){
                   if(op2 != 0){
                       if(optr.equals("+")){
                           disp.setText("");
                           /*op1 = op1 + op2;*/
                           disp.setText("Result : " + Integer.toString(op1));
                       }
                       else if(optr.equals("-")){
                           disp.setText("");/*
                           op1 = op1 - op2;*/
                           disp.setText("Result : " + Integer.toString(op1));
                       }
                       else if(optr.equals("*")){
                           disp.setText("");/*
                           op1 = op1 * op2;*/
                           disp.setText("Result : " + Integer.toString(op1));
                       }
                       else if(optr.equals("/")){
                           disp.setText("");/*
                           op1 = op1 / op2;*/
                           disp.setText("Result : " + Integer.toString(op1));
                       }
                   }
                   else{
                       operation();
                   }
               }
           break;
       }
   }
}
```

**Logcat:**

```
12-15 19:59:04.780: D/gralloc_goldfish(537): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
12-15 19:59:04.840: W/TextLayoutCache(537): computeValuesWithHarfbuzz -- need to force to single run
12-15 19:59:05.800: D/AndroidRuntime(537): Shutting down VM
12-15 19:59:05.800: W/dalvikvm(537): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409961f8)
12-15 19:59:05.850: E/AndroidRuntime(537): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-15 19:59:05.850: E/AndroidRuntime(537): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.haildark.calculator/com.one.slate.Calc}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.one.slate.Calc
12-15 19:59:05.850: E/AndroidRuntime(537):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1879)
12-15 19:59:05.850: E/AndroidRuntime(537):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
12-15 19:59:05.850: E/AndroidRuntime(537):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
12-15 19:59:05.850: E/AndroidRuntime(537):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
12-15 19:59:05.850: E/AndroidRuntime(537):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-15 19:59:05.850: E/AndroidRuntime(537):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-15 19:59:05.850: E/AndroidRuntime(537):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
12-15 19:59:05.850: E/AndroidRuntime(537):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-15 19:59:05.850: E/AndroidRuntime(537):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-15 19:59:05.850: E/AndroidRuntime(537):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
12-15 19:59:05.850: E/AndroidRuntime(537):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
12-15 19:59:05.850: E/AndroidRuntime(537):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-15 19:59:05.850: E/AndroidRuntime(537): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.one.slate.Calc
12-15 19:59:05.850: E/AndroidRuntime(537):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
12-15 19:59:05.850: E/AndroidRuntime(537):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
12-15 19:59:05.850: E/AndroidRuntime(537):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
12-15 19:59:05.850: E/AndroidRuntime(537):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023)
12-15 19:59:05.850: E/AndroidRuntime(537):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1870)
12-15 19:59:05.850: E/AndroidRuntime(537):  ... 11 more
12-15 19:59:18.140: D/gralloc_goldfish(553): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
12-15 19:59:18.181: W/TextLayoutCache(553): computeValuesWithHarfbuzz -- need to force to single run
12-15 19:59:19.191: D/AndroidRuntime(553): Shutting down VM
12-15 19:59:19.191: W/dalvikvm(553): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409961f8)
12-15 19:59:19.231: E/AndroidRuntime(553): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-15 19:59:19.231: E/AndroidRuntime(553): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.haildark.calculator/com.one.slate.Calc}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.one.slate.Calc
12-15 19:59:19.231: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1879)
12-15 19:59:19.231: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
12-15 19:59:19.231: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
12-15 19:59:19.231: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
12-15 19:59:19.231: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-15 19:59:19.231: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-15 19:59:19.231: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
12-15 19:59:19.231: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-15 19:59:19.231: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-15 19:59:19.231: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
12-15 19:59:19.231: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
12-15 19:59:19.231: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-15 19:59:19.231: E/AndroidRuntime(553): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.one.slate.Calc
12-15 19:59:19.231: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
12-15 19:59:19.231: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
12-15 19:59:19.231: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
12-15 19:59:19.231: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023)
12-15 19:59:19.231: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1870)
12-15 19:59:19.231: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  ... 11 more
```

Android Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.haildark.calculator"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.haildark.calculator.Home"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.one.slate.Calc"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.one.slate.CALC" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Is there an error? If so, please post the logcat.

Comment: It would be really helpful if you post what error you are getting.

Comment: I dont know. I looked at the logcat but I do not understand it. Running it now. Will post it up in a minute.

Comment: Check your package declaration may be u have declared it wrong

Comment: @umtek12 Please post your manifest file code.

Comment: @GrlsHu Manifest code is up.

Answer (score 0):

The manifest file declares an activity with the fully qualified name of `com.one.slate.Calc` but in code the class `Calc` is in the package `com.haildark.calculator` so the fully qualified name is `com.haildark.calculator.Calc`. Android cannot find your activity class when attempting to launch the activity.

To fix this, change the manifest class name to match your code.